# A broken image destroys login-session, why?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I use laravel framework. I have a strange problem:

When an user logs in *(so he is logged now)*, and opens a page of my website, if the page contains a broken image, then when user open a new page, he will be log out ..! So I guess when an user opens a page which contains a broken image, the login-session will be destroyed.

I mean of "broken image" is like this:

[image]

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Comment: What's the source of that html look like? Perhaps the url is being rewritten to a page for which there are not enough permissions.

Comment: yes, please share the inspect error, what is the main reason it broken. Mostly the reason is the url image can't reference the base url.

Comment: @Shiro Yes, the problem is url image .. but my question is why when there is a wrong link, the session will be destroyed?

Comment: @stack I don't get the relationship between broken image and your session. Is the image do anything with your session? Your describe very limit information. We don't get the whole picture to help you.